# Same string List data binding causing strange behavior of ComboBox control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have two comboboxes data binded to the same list of strings:

```
cbo1.DataSource    = niches_list.LIST_niches;
cbo1.DisplayMember = "LIST_niches";             
cbo2.DataSource    = niches_list.LIST_niches;
cbo2.DisplayMember = "LIST_niches";
```

It all loads well but when I change the selected item of cbo1 then cbo2 changes the selection also; the reverse holds: if I change the selected item of cbo2 the selected item of cbo1 changes to the same index. Why is this? Is there a fix?

Comment: Sounds like your binding is two-way, you may need to set it to one way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) to keep the two comboboxes currency management distinct

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = niches_list.LIST_niches
cbo1.DisplayMember = "LIST_niches";             
cbo1.DataSource = bs;

BindingSource bs2 = new BindingSource();
bs2.DataSource = niches_list.LIST_niches;
cbo2.DisplayMember = "LIST_niches";             
cbo2.DataSource = bs2;
```

A `BindingSource` object has many functionality as explained in the link to the class documentation. In your case the important one is the `currency management` meaning that it handles the current position over the underlying data source in behalf of its client (the combobox). The [BindingSource.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.current(v=vs.110).aspx) property is different between the two instances and this is the key to keep the two comboboxes selected item separated.